# Combine/Merge arrays that have the same keys PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has some keys that are repeating multiple times. Would like to combine them so that I can have them in one array, within the same array.
I have an array of this type;

```
Array
(
    [Shoes] => Array
        (
            [POLO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Size5
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [Shoes] => Array
        (
            [FUBU] => Array
                (
                    [0] => size6
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [Bag] => Array
        (
            [HPBAG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Black
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [Bag] => Array
        (
            [HPBAG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => White
                )

        )

)
```

I would like an output of the following kind;

```
Array
    (
        [Shoes] => Array
            (
                [POLO] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => size5
                    )
                [FUBU] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => size6
                    )
    
            )

        [Bag] => Array
            (
                [HPBAG] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Black
                        [1] => White
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

I have tried array_merge, array_merge_recursive but all are not working.

```
foreach ($county as $value) { print_r(array_merge($value)); } //$value contains the array 

foreach ($county as $value) { print_r(array_merge_recursive($value)); } //$value contains the array
```

Kindly assist if you have an idea on how to solve this in PHP.

Comment: Any code to show? You mention an attempt but you fail to show that attempt. `not working` is not something that can be debugged with intelligence. Has to be a specific error (logical or syntax) that is not working.

Comment: @GetSet foreach ($county as $value) {

              print_r(array_merge($value));
            } //$value contains the array

Comment: @Remy Kindly share some code

Comment: Abiudeko, you should really consider putting your code in your question, not here in comments. Comments are for tips. Not for posting your code. I get it you did post the data structure. And while that is code in some aspects and helps greatly, your code is also equally important for debugging.

Comment: @GetSet Okay, let me update, but that withstanding, do you have an idea of the solution, please?

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted so this may get some attention. On cursory look I dont have a solution myself. I do have an iterative solution involving an explicit loop. However likely this can be solved more succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a few nested `array_walk()` calls:

```
$arr=array(array("Shoes" => array("POLO" => array("Size5"))),
      array("Shoes" => array("FUBU" => array("size6"))),
      array("Bag" => array("HPBAG" => array("Black"))),
      array("Bag" => array("HPBAG" => array("White"))));

$res=[];
array_walk($arr,function($a) use (&$res){ 
    array_walk($a, function($ar,$type) use (&$res){
        array_walk($ar, function ($arr,$brand) use (&$res,$type){
            $res[$type][$brand]=array_merge($res[$type][$brand]??[],$arr);
        });
    });
});

print_r($res);
```

See the demo here: https://rextester.com/RFLQ18142

It produces this result:

```
Array
(
    [Shoes] => Array
        (
            [POLO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Size5
                )

            [FUBU] => Array
                (
                    [0] => size6
                )

        )

    [Bag] => Array
        (
            [HPBAG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Black
                    [1] => White
                )

        )

)
```